# Share Data Between Visual Web Parts on different pages

Tags: visual-web-part, session, data

I have a need to share information from Web Parts on one page, with Web Parts on a second page. SharePoint does not have a default Session State, and let's say for arguments sake I cannot enable Session.

If there is a LOT of information, more than can be sent via Query String, is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this in several ways depending on the amount of data that you need to share. The basic idea would be to have a central repository on which the web parts can read and write data.

1. Use a Custom List within the site to be read and updated.
2. Custom SQL database.
3. Use Property bags in SharePoint - Read [this blog](http://mikkokoskinen.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/sharepoint-application-configuration-part-1-property-bag/) for detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

What about storing it in a cookie?